# How to retrieve PAYLOAD for a Google Cloud Task via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Is it possible to retrieve the PAYLOAD (see image below of what I can view in GCP's Cloud Tasks UI) for a GCP Cloud Task via Google's API? If so, how? Here's the `Task` documentation I've been looking through (I can't see anything that would get me the PAYLOAD): https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-tasks/latest/com.google.cloud.tasks.v2.Task

[image: GCP Cloud Task PAYLOAD]

I also ran `gcloud tasks describe [TASK] --response-view=full` and couldn't see the PAYLOAD anywhere in the response.

This seems like obvious functionality, so I'm hoping I'm missing something (different API, perhaps). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (!?) this is excluded from `Task` on retrieval perhaps for security reasons but, it appears not possible to get the request body from tasks in the queue.

**Note**: On way to investigate this is to use e.g. Chrome's Developer Tools to understand how Console achieves this.

You can validate this using `gcloud` and [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer):

```bash
 gcloud tasks list \
--queue=${QUEUE} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
 --format=yaml \
--log-http
```

**Note**: You don't need the `--format` to use `--log-http` but I was using both.

Or: [`projects.locations.queues.tasks.list`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/list) and filling in the blanks (you don't need to include API key).

Even though all should be [`Task`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task) in my case (using [`HttpRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#HttpRequest), the response does not include `body`.

IIRC, when I used Cloud Tasks a while ago, I was similarly perplexed at being unable to access response bodies.

Comment: Thanks! I'm perplexed as to how we're expected to differentiate one Task in a Queue from another. Sure, we get the task "id" from the `taskName`, but that's only useful if we keep track of that when we actually queue up the task (which is burdensome, because we're retrieving tasks in a totally separate area at a totally different time, so we'd have to store this in a DB or something). Do you happen to know if there's a way to pass the payload as URL query params such that they'd appear when viewing the `HttpRequest` (or `AppEngineHttpRequest`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a combination of [list_tasks](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudtasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks_v2.services.cloud_tasks.CloudTasksClient#google_cloud_tasks_v2_services_cloud_tasks_CloudTasksClient_list_tasks:%7E:text=Lists%20the%20tasks%20in%20a%20queue.) and [get_task](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudtasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks_v2.services.cloud_tasks.CloudTasksClient#google_cloud_tasks_v2_services_cloud_tasks_CloudTasksClient_get_task:%7E:text=task.Task-,Gets%20a%20task,-.) methods from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudtasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks_v2.services.cloud_tasks.CloudTasksClient#methods). Below is a python example:

```py
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
import json

# create a client
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

queue_path = client.queue_path('<project_id>', '<location>', '<queue_id>')

# list the tasks in the queue
request = tasks.ListTasksRequest(parent=queue_path)
response = client.list_tasks(request=request)

# get task details
for task in response:

    request_task_info = tasks_v2.GetTaskRequest(name=task.name, response_view='FULL')
    task_info = client.get_task(request=request_task_info)

    # get payload from details
    payload = json.loads(task_info.http_request.body)
    print(payload)
```

Also see the [list](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/list?hl=en#:%7E:text=projects.locations.queues.tasks.list) and [get](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/get?hl=en#:%7E:text=projects.locations.queues.tasks.get) HTTP request methods.